# When I Use Angular2 WebPack in Asp Core : An unhandled exception occurrs while processing the request

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, angular2-template, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using Angular2 WebPack in Asp Core .

I'm using This Template : [Template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)

I've deleted : `Home , Counter , Fetch Data ( HTML , Ts )` ,also deleted Import in app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Now When I run the project, It Shows the following error :

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.`

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?
>   at E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6921:27
>   at ZoneDelegate.invoke (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:232:26)
>   at Object.onInvoke (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6242:41)
>   at ZoneDelegate.invoke (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:231:32)
>   at Zone.run (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:114:43)
>   at NgZoneImpl.runInner (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6269:75)
>   at NgZone.run (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6499:70)
>   at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6916:27)
>   at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModuleFactory (E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6904:25)
>   at E:\MyProject\Angular2Application6\Angular2Application6\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.js:439:38

Whats the problem ? How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the module `BrowserModule` is missing, you can try adding the module using:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ]
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent
    ]
 })
   export class AppModule {
}
```

If the error is not solved maybe you can check if you are using angular 2 RC4 to update the release version to RC5, because `NgModule` was introduced in Angular 2 RC5.

Comment: When i Undo the folders its work fine . but when i delete that it show me that error

Comment: You can update your `package.json` to refer to the version `2.0.0-rc.5` and make a `npm install`. Maybe it would be nice to include the code because it seems like some file is trying to import/use that module

Comment: when i use `npm install` it show me this : `npm WARN Angular2Spa@2.0.0-rc.5 No repository field.
npm WARN Angular2Spa@2.0.0-rc.5 No license field.`